# .sort method not working, any hints why is that?

Tags: javascript, sorting, methods

```
const sortYears = function (arr){
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a})
    }



 const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922]

 console.log(sortYears(years))
```

The output: undefined. The output I was expecting: [ 2018, 2011, 1999, 1982, 1970, 1963, 1951, 1922 ]
Thanks a million for any help here

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything and yet you are logging the return value of the function. Either return something or do `console.log(years)`.

Comment: `const sortYears = (arr) => arr.sort( (a, b)=> b - a );`

Answer (score 2):

You need to return  the value from the function

```js
const sortYears = function (arr){
    return arr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a})
}

const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922]
console.log(sortYears(years))
```

`sort()` methods modifies the original array. In the above snippet the `years` array is also changed.

If don't want to modify the original array make sure to clone it first using spread syntax.

```js
const sortYears = function (arr){
    return [...arr].sort(function(a, b){return b - a})
}

const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922];
const res= sortYears(years);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
console.log(JSON.stringify(years));
```

Comment: Or do `console.log(years)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const sortYears = function (arr){
    arr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a})
      return arr;
    }



 const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922]

 console.log(sortYears(years))
```

`you did not return the sorted array back`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are not returning anything from `sortYears()` function.

```
const sortYears = function (arr){
    return arr.sort(function(a, b){return b - a})
}
```

Here i am using the shorter syntax using arrow function.

```js
const sortYears = arr => arr.sort((a,b)=> b-a);

const years = [1970, 1999, 1951, 1982, 1963, 2011, 2018, 1922]
console.log(sortYears(years))
```